# index.html file malfunction

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I'm using Joomla CMS for developing a site at my local computer with OpenServer. I know that a simple index.html file (`<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>`) placed in directories will prevent foreign access of files contained in this directory, but it's not working, and files are shown as a result.

How can I prevent the directory listing from being seen?

Comment: Content of index.html file is as usual: <!DOCTYPE html><title></title>

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` is not configured to look for `index.html` files in the first place then, probably.

Comment: What version of OpenServer are you running?

Comment: Yeah, this was DirectoryIndex problem, thanks to all for helping

Answer (score 0):

> I know that a simple index.html file

No.

Your issue arises from the webserver and how it is configured. Nothing to do with PHP. Nothing to do with Joomla. I have never heard of a webserver named openserver, [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenServer) [neither](https://ospanel.io/) [has](https://www.petex.com/products/ipm-suite/openserver/) [google](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openserver/).

Perhaps if you shared its config someone might recognise it.